# Best way in PHP to ensure in a class that all the class functions are called only if a given condition is true

Tags: php

I have a class in which each function of the class have to check the exact same condition before executing its code:

```
class myObject
{
    public function function1($argument)
    {
        if($condition === true)
        {
            //Do Something
        }
    }

    public function function2($argument)
    {
        if($condition === true)
        {
            //Do Something
        }
    }

    public function function3($argument)
    {
        if($condition === true)
        {
            //Do Something
        }
    }

    public function function4($argument)
    {
        if($condition === true)
        {
            //Do Something
        }
    }
}
```

We can see that function1, function2, function3, function4 only execute their code if `$condition === true`.

If in the future I add another function called function5, I will have to duplicate this condition.

**So my question is, what is the best way to ensure that before call ANY function in the class, a condition is true, and if the condition is false, not call the function.**

My method is to use the magic function __call and make all the functions of the class private:

```
class myObject
{

    public function __call($method,$args)
    {
        if($condition === true)
        {
            call_user_func_array(array($this,$method),$args);
        }

        return;
    }

    private function function1($argument)
    {
            //Do Something
    }

    private function function2($argument)
    {
            //Do Something
    }

    private function function3($argument)
    {
            //Do Something
    }

    private function function4($argument)
    {
            //Do Something
    }
}
```

It seems to work. However, I'm unsure that it will always work and that it is a clever way of doing it.

Comment: I'd stick with your first method for clarity, but your __call() alternative will surely work. I guess it's a matter of preference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its pretty normal to do it your first way. But, maybe the whole design of the class is wrong? If every single one function needs the exact same condition to be true maybe you could set/check it in the constructor and treat it from there? Why recheck the condition multiple times? Can it change between function calls?

Something like that would be used this way:

```
    try{
       $myClass = new MyClass(); // if no permissions throw exception
    }catch(Exception $e){
       //do something
       return false;
    }
//we know user as permission we go on
    $myClass->function1();
    $myClass->function2();
```

The second way works but you lose some of the power of phpdoc and good editors that will autocomplete your code. This way you have to know the name of every method.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! The problem is that the condition changes. I simplified the code, but the condition is actually a call to an external function like $myOtherObject->isActivated(); which return true or false. I also don't control the code calling $myClass->function1(). In reality, $myClass is an Observer on an Event. When the event occurs, all the observers for this event are called and there is no try catch for exceptions. Also, throwing an exception would mean that there is a fatal error, which is not the case.

Comment: Well then you should really edit your question and make it more clear what is going on. How can we help if the example is not really representative?